# How to change Kustomize version in kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kustomize

I just wondering how I can change/update the version of kustomize in kubectl
[kubetcl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeVqy.png)
Now I have that and I want to have kustomize version 5.1.0

I have download kustomize 5.1.0 with choco but kubetcl still using kustomize 5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot update the version of Kustomize embedded in `kubectl` (other than by installing a newer version of `kubectl` that happens to use a more recent version of Kustomize).

Just use the standalone Kustomize binary if you want the newer version; instead of `kubectl apply -k .` you can `kustomize build | kubectl apply -f-`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
So if i have the lastest version of kubetcl and i need a higher version of kustomize my only solution is to do ```kustomize build | kubectl apply -f```

Comment: That's correct. I guess there would be some possibility of patching the sources yourself, but I'm not sure how easy that is.